# Fragmentary serial print

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to print my ultrasound distance measurements right after taking the measurement:

```cpp
int i,result = 0, values[51];
for(i=0;i<51;i++){
    result = TakeMeasurement; // UltraSound Measurement
    Serial.print("Nr.");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(result);
    values[i++] = result;
    delay(150);
}
```

When I run this code the serial monitor shows:

```
Nr.0: 44
Nr.2: 45
Nr.4: 45
Nr.6: 46
Nr.8: 45
```

.... up to `Nr. 50`.

Where are the uneven numbers?

Comment: I wonder where the numbers come from at all, since you print `"Nr."`  and then immediately print `": "`.

Comment: sorry missed a line.

Comment: I moved it to the place where it probably is, given your output. When sharing code, please share the *actual* code. It prevents confusion, especially when we're looking at your code in details, looking for some weird small thingy like a surplus of `++` signs. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You increase it twice: once in the loop head (`i++`) and then when you add to `values`: `values[i++]`.